# limitation in drawing route using map api in iphone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios6-maps

i have used [this](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions)  link to draw route on map. I am using iOS 6 map view. but i think this is using google map api to draw route on map. when i drop 26th pins it gives me error.

I want to know is this a limitations from google map? What is role of way pointes and if i want to drop more than 25+ pins one by one then what should i do ? Can anyone provide me a link in which we can draw routes between more than 25 pins continuously? if not is there any other way ?

Error messege is : A direction request could not be successfully parsed. Error code 400

Plz help

Answer (score 0):

As i remember a limitation for request to google maps api is 250 per day for one application. I also remeber that google can stop responce when you send to many request for some part of time.
Tell what string did you get from google maps api with this 26th point?

Comment: i get " A direction request could not be successfully parsed. Error code 400" this .

Comment: I didnt use this code, but you must find the place where you get responce from google (it will be JSON data) and see the content of that JSON, becouse it maybe a google responce error and you get empty JSON file, but it also can be JSON parser error.

Comment: i am getting this error in : - (void)directions:(UICGDirections *)directions didFailWithMessage:(NSString *)message method. which is UICGDirectionsDelegate method

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that software is using the [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), which has a [limitation of 25 waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GDirections.loadFromWaypoints).  The Google Maps API v3 has a limitation of 10 waypoints (start, end and 8 waypoints) which can be increased to 25 with a Business license.

Also, FYI the Google Maps API v2 is deprecated, and may stop working as early as May 2013.

Comment: so what should be the solution to this? Can i drop 23 pins(or 7 pins as waypoints) and then again use 7 or 23 way points from end point and thus i can continuously draw map

Comment: Here is an [example that combines multiple requests to the Google  Maps API v3 directions service](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html), from [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083639/google-maps-v3-waypoints-infowindow-with-random-text).