# How can I pair driving directions route segments with the names of the route in Google Maps API V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a driving directions app that gives me turn-by-turn directions. The start, end, and waypoints come from my form, which looks something like this:

```
    <b>Start</b>
    <select id="startdrop" name="startthere">
    ALL MY OPTIONS
    <option selected value="COMPLETEADDRESS"><%= LOCATIONNAME %></option>
    </select>

    Stops Along the Way
    <select multiple id="waypoints" name="waypointsselected[]">
    <option selected value="COMPLETEADDRESS"><%= LOCATIONNAME %></option>
    </select>           

    <b>End</b>
    <select id="enddrop" name="endthere">
    ALL MY OPTIONS
    <option selected value="COMPLETEADDRESS"><%= LOCATIONNAME %></option>
    </select>
```

My goal is to get the LOCATIONNAME to appear in the infowindow for each point and in the route summary. For every point from start to waypoints to end, the summary should look like this:

```
    A Great House
    136 Utica Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11213, USA to 

    Knights Baptist Church
    180 Utica Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11213
```

Please see below for my attempt. The problems right now: the "StartText" is the same for every route, and the Waypoints break the javascript because the array is empty:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    function calcRoute() {
          var start = document.getElementById("startdrop").value;
          var startSelect = document.getElementById("startdrop");
          var startText = startSelect.options[startSelect.selectedIndex].text;
          var end = document.getElementById("enddrop").value;
          var endSelect = document.getElementById("enddrop");
          var endText = startSelect.options[endSelect.selectedIndex].text;
              var waypts = [];
          var waypointText = [];
          var checkboxArray = document.getElementById("waypoints");
          for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
             waypts.push({
                  location:checkboxArray[i].value,
                  waypointText:checkboxArray[i].text,
                  stopover:true
              });
         }

   var request = {
              origin: start,
              destination: end,
              waypoints: waypts,
              optimizeWaypoints: optimize,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
              var route = response.routes[0];
              var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");

              summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
              // For each route, display summary information.
              for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                var routeSegment = i+1;
                summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";


                summaryPanel.innerHTML += startText + "</b><br />";
                summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
                summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br />";
                summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].duration.text + "<br /><br />";
```

**Edit 1**

There is some information here about recreating the map, which may work ([Google Maps V3 - waypoints + infowindow with random text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083639/google-maps-v3-waypoints-infowindow-with-random-text)), but if there's a different, more efficient approach, I'd sure love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

The DirectionsStep object has a property called end_location. You could get this value and display it in an info window?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsLeg

Comment: Barnaby, thank you for your response, but according to the same documentation, end_location creates a LatLng object representing a geographic point. I am already displaying end_address in the summary panel. Long-story short, this by itself won't show LOCATIONNAME.

Comment: You can use reverse Geocoding to turn the LatLng into an address - see this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Comment: Barnaby, I'm trying to list "A Great House" or "Knights Baptist Church" as part of the route summary. The approach you mention above will only display the address, which I already have in the route summary.